# How does cache busting work on the index.html?

Tags: http, caching

The main two ways to cache bust are:

1. hash inside filename: styles.hash123.css
2. hash inside path: styles.css?v=version1.23

I understand the reason and mechanisms behind this.

However what I do not understand is how to cache bust the index.html of a website, for example a SPA.
The browser cache could keep the index.html of the SPA for a long time and thus the css/js files would never get cache busted.

Is the index.html handled as a special case by browsers or could the described behaviour happen?

Comment: You could use a server-side code architecture, which are not cached like (.php, .aspx, .jsp). Also, you could add headers that request no caching.

Comment: You should add a "Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" header to your HTML file.

Answer (score 5):

Add to your HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```